# assign_vertex_id error

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I am trying to test if pgrouting works fine or not. To do so I have created a table containing the following attributes.

```
  Columns:
 gid      |
 length   |
 the_geom |
 source   |
 target
```

Now my problem is that when I try to execute the assign_vertex_id function it is giving me the following error;

```
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 32 at EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
SQL state: 22004


Context: PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 32 at EXECUTE statement
```

Any suggestions what does this mean?

Comment: It would be easier to figure out if you showed the column types, any indexes and constraints (basically, the output of `\d` would be good), and *especially* the failing query. Somehow you have a function running an `EXECUTE` statement as dynamically generated SQL, but the string it's being passed is `NULL`. One way this could happen is to concatenate a series of values where one of them is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

assign_vertex_id() is defined as part of PGrouting in [routing_topology.sql](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/core/sql/routing_topology.sql#L56). (Running `\df+ assign_vertex_id` would also give you the current source.) Line 32's EXECUTE statement is:

```
EXECUTE 'update ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || 
    ' SET source = ' || source_id || 
    ', target = ' || target_id || 
    ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(gid_cname) || ' =  ' || _r.id;
```

The error is that EXECUTE is being called with a NULL argument. How? Well, the SQL `||` operator means concatenate, and concatenating NULL to a string results in NULL:

```
=> select ('string' || null) is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

My guess is the `gid` column of the underlying table (`_r.id` here) contains NULLs, although I suppose it could be source/target_id too. Fix it, then add a constraint to prevent that going forward:

```
ALTER TABLE whatever ALTER COLUMN gid SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The gid colun is already set to not null. This is the structure of the table;

CREATE TABLE way
(
  gid integer NOT NULL,
  length double precision,
  the_geom geometry(MultiLineString,4326),
  source integer,
  target integer,
  CONSTRAINT gid PRIMARY KEY (gid )
)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Postgis 2.0 and have a table with Multilinestrings?

The function ST_StartPoint() and ST_EndPoint() does not work on Multilinestrings anymore(http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html) in Postgis 2.0. So it will most likely fail there.

You need to convert your Multilinestrings to Linestrings. More info about that here: